# Random simple queries are failing on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

For the BQ team, queries that usually work, are failing sometimes.

Could you please look into what could be the issue, there is just this:

```
Error: Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID: aerobic-forge-504:job_DTFuQEeVGwZbt-PRFbMVE6TCz0U
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the slow response.

BigQuery replicates data to multiple datacenters and may run queries from any of them. Usually this is transparent ... if your data hasn't replicated everywhere, we will try to find a datacenter that has all of the data necessary to run a query and execute the query from there.

The error you hit was due to BigQuery not being able to find a single datacenter that had all of the data for one of your tables. We try very hard to make sure this doesn't happen. In principle, it should be very rare (we've got solution designed to make sure that it never happens, but haven't finished the implementation yet). We saw an uptick in this issue this morning, and have a bug filed and are currently investigating the issue.

Was this a transient error? If you retry the operation, does it work now? Are you still getting errors on other queries?

Comment: I will let you know if happens again.